# Backbone collection.where

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am retrieving a model from a backbone collection.

`var organisation = this.collection.where({ group_id : String(elm.data('groupid')) });`

this returns a result as I would expect it too.

I then when to do some getting and setting on that model, but if I try and run,

`organisation.get('members')`

then I get the following error message,

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I am assuming (maybe wrongly) that is because where() does not acutally return  model?

If that is the case then how can I cast the returned data into a model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `findWhere` instead. [Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere)

> Just like where, but directly returns only the first model in the collection that matches the passed attributes

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where):

> ### where
>
> `collection.where(attributes)`
>
> Return an **array** of all the models in a collection that match the passed attributes. Useful for simple cases of filter

You're getting an array of records back. If you want to work with one of the returned records, either:

```
organisation[0].get('members')
```

or

```
organisation = organisation[0];
organisation.get('members')
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to turn the array into a model?

Comment: @Udders "Turn an array into a model"? No, you just need to get the model out of the array. My second option specifically says `organisation = organisation[0]`.

Comment: @Udders in this case you should check `organisation.length != 0` first or you risk to get exception